# Creating testcases using nunit and moq on WEB API controllers

Tags: nunit, moq, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a unit test cases using nunit on controllers in an existing Web API project.
I am using Moq as mocking framework. In here I would like to mock repository to return some expected 
result.I am not sure what I can do at the point of setting up of repository mockup and validating result.
Can somebody suggest if whatever I am doing it right ? I just took a random controller for this question. 
Any advise or guidance to some example url would be greatly appreciated.

```
[TestCase]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    AccountController ac = new AccountController();
    var mockAuthRepository = new Mock<AuthRepository>();
    //mockAuthRepository.Setup(m=>m.RegisterUser(It.IsAny<UserModel>))
}


[RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
private readonly AuthRepository _repo;
    public AccountController()
    {
        _repo = new AuthRepository();
    }
}

[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Users = "admin")]
[Route("Register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(UserModel userModel)
{
    IdentityResult result = await _repo.RegisterUser(userModel);
    IHttpActionResult errorResult = WrapError(result);
    if (errorResult != null)
    {
        return errorResult;
    }
    return Ok();
}
private IHttpActionResult WrapError(IdentityResult result)
{
    if (result == null)
    {
        return InternalServerError();
    }
    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        if (result.Errors != null)
        {
            foreach (string err in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", err);
        }
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your any specific test use setups like these:

```
mockAuthRepository
  .Setup(m => m.RegisterUser(It.IsAny<UserModel>))
  .Returns(new List<UserModel> {
    new UserModel { // specific properties },
    new UserModel { // specific properties },
    new UserModel { // specific properties }
  }.AsQueryable());
```

And then just make assertion for selected users.

For example, you can test Register method to prevent registering existing user by placing in mockAuthRepository the same user that was in controller input and assert that specific error code is generated.

You can also use mocks to check if some code is called by using Verify method with param Times.Once, Times.Never etc..

Good luck!